# Magento 2: How to Override Block in Custom Module

Tags: magento2, cart, blocks, overrides

I want to overide cart item Renderer Block in custom extension. 
This is my Block file but this is not work

```
 <?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Vendor name\Modulename\Block\Cart\Item;

/**
 * Shopping cart item render block
 *
 * @author      Magento Core Team <core@magentocommerce.com>
 *
 * @method \Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer setProductName(string)
 * @method \Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer setDeleteUrl(string)
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
 */
class Renderer extends \Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer implements
    \Magento\Framework\DataObject\IdentityInterface
{
     public function getFormatedOptionValue($optionValue)
    {

        /* @var $helper \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\Configuration */

        if(isset($optionValue['value']))
        { 
            $directory = 'http://localhost/dtooladvance/pub/media/designtool/designImages/'.$optionValue['value'];
            $optionValue['value'] = "<img src='".$directory."' />";
            return $optionValue;
        }


        $helper = $this->_productConfig;
        $params = [
            'max_length' => 55,
            'cut_replacer' => ' <a href="#" class="dots tooltip toggle" onclick="return false">...</a>'
        ];
        return $helper->getFormattedOptionValue($optionValue, $params);
    }


}
```

How I override Renderer block in custom extension for magento 2.

Comment: have you created `di.xml` file?

Comment: please update your question with proper Information , in comment people can't understand easily @Rahulocodewire

Comment: i want to override the "Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer block but this is not work please tell me how i make the block file in the custom extension .

Comment: vender_name is missing bro.  `namespace vendername\Modulename\Block\Cart\Item;` And implements no need for override any class

Comment: post your module di,xml file to comment.

Answer (score 0):

By using preference you can override any class

eg.

**di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="\Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer" type="<your_vendername>\<your_modulename>\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer"/>
</config>
```

**root\app\code\your_vendername\your_modulename\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer.php**

```
<?php

namespace your_vendername\your_modulename\Block\Cart\Item;

class Renderer extends \Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer
{


}
```

Comment: i created this di.xml file problme in my block file